# Starting Off With Spoon

Tags: java, maven, inria-spoon

I'm completely new to Spoon and have very basic knowledge of Maven,

So my question is, where do I start off with Spoon. I've read the "Getting Started" guide over and over but I've hit a wall at the "Apply the processor" section.

Any help/advice would be greatly appreciated

Comment: This is much too general for this site.

Comment: Does this help: https://github.com/INRIA/spoon/pull/1676/files?

Comment: @MartinMonperrus This does help alot thank you :). I just have to clarify somethings. (1) Are all the processors you create supposed to be in a separate project to the actual Spoon project. (2) What is the "Binary of your processor" as mentioned in "$ java -classpath /path/to/binary/of/your/processor.jar:spoon-core".